# Why is devise and warden not logging in the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, warden

Here is my user session controller create action that the login goes through

```
# POST /resource/sign_in
def create
  resource = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])  
  # check for inactive
  redirect_to(new_user_session_path, :notice => 'Invalid Email Address or Password.') and return if resource.try(:active) == false
  # check to see if user is AD user
  if ad_resource?(resource) 
    if !ActiveDirectory.new.authenticate!(params[:user][:email], params[:user][:password])
      redirect_to new_user_session_path, :notice => 'Invalid Email Address or Password.'
      return
    end
  else
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
  end

  set_flash_message :notice, :signed_in
  sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
end
```

this line

```
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
```

How can that possible login anyone...I am not as familiar to devise and i am trying to login and i know there is an active user in the db but i cant log in and looking at the warden.authenticate line confuses me because it doensnt pass in the email and password...any help would be great to help me understand what is happening in the authentication

Answer (score 0):

There is a warden initializer file its run as middleware that picks up the correct params when used with devise...

Have a look at the [warden gem](https://github.com/hassox/warden) to understand how it works fully.

Personally i find devise gets in the way very quickly and you might be better understanding how it all works if you 'roll' your own authentication system.